# JSP,SQL retrieving data returning null

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

why does the view return a null ?  thanks in advance.

this is my view jsp

```
String abb = "ab";
String cdd = "cd";
UserPass user = UserDb.selectUser(abb,cdd);
out.println(user);
```

and this is my UserPass class

```
public class UserPass {
    String username;
    String password;

    public UserPass(){
       this.username ="";
       this.password ="";     
    }

    public void setUserName(String username) {
       this.username = username;
    }

    public String getUserName(){ 
       return username;
    }
}
```

and finally the data package, UserDb

```
String query = "select user_name from UserPass where user_name = ? AND user_password = ? " ;

try{
    ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setString(1, username);
    ps.setString(2, password);

    rs = ps.executeQuery();

    if (rs.getString("user_name") != null) {
        UserPass up = new UserPass();
        up.setUserName(rs.getString("user_name"));
        return up;

    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

My database is simple and the entries are there user_name and user_password. The view returns null

Comment: can you post the code on your `view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [rs.next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) to check if the current row is valid first:

```
rs = ps.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
    UserPass up = new UserPass();
    up.setUserName(rs.getString("user_name"));
    return up;
} else {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: thanks !, can you help me understand, if let's say I want to use an if statement with a condition to validate a resultset content ?

Comment: The `if (rs.getString("user_name") != null)` block is actually completely superfluous. It's exactly that block which needs to be replaced altogether by a `if (rs.next())`.

Comment: D'oh, yes of course, `user_name` is the only field being brought back :)

Comment: Thanks alot, I wish I can just simply upload the technology into my brain, can you recommend me a resource for learning this from your experience if you don't mind ? something that will save me trouble, am jumping from one book to another but still i get stuck with stuff like that

Comment: @TrackmeifYouCan: If you're new to JDBC, then I would recommend going through the ["Lesson: JDBC Basics"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/) tutorials. They're pretty good :)

Comment: any idea why my other question here is not responded ? am i asking something wrong?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377787/displaying-multiple-entries-from-a-table-in-jsp-through-an-object-not-resultset